# Exclude Files When Deploying from Git to Azure Websites

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

**Question:**

I would like to exclude certain files (by type) from my Azure Websites deployment. Can this be done without creating a custom deployment file?

**Given:**

- Deploying an MVC 4 web application from a local Git repository
- Want to exclude *.coffee (CoffeeScript) files from the site deployment, but not from my Git repo
- Scoured the Kudu wiki (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki), but haven't found an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that these CoffeeScript files are listed in your csproj file, such that they show up in Visual Studio?

All you should have to do is make sure the Build Action is set to None and not to Content, and they won't get deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply David. Yes, the CoffeeScript files are listed in my project file. That sounds like a good solution; however, I have quite a few files, so it would be a bit tedious at first. And, then I would also have to remember to change that setting every time I added a new file. I'm going to try the other posted solution as well. I'll let you know which is easiest.

Comment: Yes, please try Ahmed's solution. Post deployment actions have not been widely used, so it would be nice to see them put to good use!

Comment: As for the Build Action, note that you can multi-select all your coffeescript files in solution explorer, and change it all at once. You could also hand edit your csproj file. But yes, it's a pain point for each new file.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this is through a [post deployment action](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks) that runs a batch file like this

```
cd /d %HOME%\site\wwwroot
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b *.coffee') do del %%i
```

You can use an echo though first to make sure it's deleting the correct files

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b *.coffee') do echo %%i >> toBeDeleted.txt
```

Comment: @amelsayed This seems like a decent solution, I'm going to try this and David's and I'll let you know which works best. Thanks!